# C - dup2 stdin make dup2 stdout and stderr stop printing

Tags: c

I'm having  a strange problem. I'm currently creating two programs, one will execute on background and the other one will read its output and also allow to make inputs to the other one running on background.

The problem is, when I put the line `dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO)` the program executing on background stops printing to the files.

The Reader:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
int main()
{

    int out, err, in;
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    int offErr = 0, offOut = 0;
    char bufErr[1024];
    char bufOut[1024];
    char *cFifo = "/tmp/out";
    char *cFifoErr = "/tmp/err";
    char *cFifoIn = "/tmp/in";

    out = open(cFifo, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0600);

    err = open(cFifoErr, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0600);

    in = open(cFifoIn, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0600);


    while(1)
    {
        memset(bufOut, 0, 1024);
        memset(bufErr, 0, 1024);
        i=0;
        j=0;
        while(!i && !j)
        {
            j = pread(err, bufErr, 1024, offErr);
            i = pread(out, bufOut, 1024, offOut);
            offOut +=i;
            offErr +=j;
        }
        if(i)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, bufOut, 1024);
        if(j)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, bufErr, 1024);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the Writer (background):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    int out, in, err;

    char *cFifo = "/tmp/out";
    char *cInFifo = "/tmp/in";
    char *cErrFifo = "/tmp/err";

    out = open(cFifo, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600);
    in = open("/tmp/in", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600);
    err = open(cErrFifo, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600);

    dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(err, STDERR_FILENO);
    //dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO); //if  I uncomment this it stops printing to out or err

    system("python");

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the return code from dup2?

Comment: Are the names in `/tmp` actually FIFOs as the names used suggest?  Is `Reader` or `Writter` (writer?) the one running in the background?  How do you run the command running in the background?  How do you run the command running in the foreground?    The Reader code opens file descriptor `in` and never uses it — why?  You're using positioned reads — why are you waiting until there's data at offset 1024 before reading anything?  (If they're FIFOs, then the seeking is meaningless anyway.)  In the writer, you have unnecessary file descriptors open when you run "python".

Comment: It is not waiting for a 1024 offset of data, it reads the available data, and the offset is set from the last reading char

Answer (score 0):

When you uncomment:

```
//dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO); //if  I uncomment this it stops printing to out or err
```

you are making Python read from an empty file (it was created and/or truncated when you opened it), so Python gets nothing to do and exits.

Your reader code then sits in the `while (1) ;` loop doing nothing useful.

At the very least, add a `printf()` after the `system()` statement so you know when the Python command has completed.

Comment: I have done that, it is not that the problem, even using fflsh(stdout) to guarantee everything is sent

Comment: But if that was the case is any way of working around it? Thank you :)

Comment: Since there's no writing to the input file before the Python command is run, and since you've not answered my question about whether the names called `cInFifo` etc are actually FIFOs as the variable name suggests, or whether they're files as the `O_CREAT` option suggests, it is hard to know what you expect to happen.  However, taken at face value, as coded, and with no setup, you run Python with an empty input, which means Python exits immediately (successfully).  You writer process then drops into the spin-loop.  You don't test for open errors. You might get `-1` from `pread()`.